# xamarin android auto resize the google map

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new to the android xamarin. I need to resize the map based on source point and destination point. I have received the map as attached(SCREEN[image] A.png) when i draw the route between source and destination. But i need the map as (SCREEN B.png). Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've created your route just zoom to the coordinates of your startpoint. Use the zoom functionality of Google maps. I've you want to enable the user to zoom and scroll manually, use:

```
                GoogleMap _map;
                _map.UiSettings.ScrollGesturesEnabled = true;
                _map.UiSettings.ZoomGesturesEnabled = true;
                _map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = true;
```

Code to zoom to coordinates:

```
            CameraPosition.Builder builder = CameraPosition.InvokeBuilder();
            builder.Target(new LatLng(YOURLATITUDE,YOURLONGITUDE));
            builder.Zoom(12f);
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = builder.Build();
            googleMap.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            //OR ANIMATED
            googleMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: I'm glad it can help you! You should mark the solution as answered if the answer satisfies your needs.